# How can I change text inside a modal with jquery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hello guys I tried to create a pokedex by using pokeapi.
My modal looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"> #1 Pokemon-Name</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Some information
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the js like this:

```
const button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
button.setAttribute("data-toggle","modal");
button.setAttribute("data-target","#exampleModalCenter");
```

And my question is how can I change the title and the description of the modal to bulbasaur ?

Full Code: https://www.codeply.com/go/qoCnPUDDxG

Comment: Give each element that contains text / data that you wish to change a unique ID attribute and do `$('#unique_id').html('Text / Data here');`.

Answer (score 2):

With plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('exampleModalLongTitle').textContent = 'Bulbasaur';
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#exampleModalLongTitle').html("Bulbasaur");
```

Do the same for whichever element contains your description.

Answer (score 0):

For the modal title:

```
document.getElementById("exampleModalLongTitle").innerHTML="bulbasaur"; //pure JS
$("#exampleModalLongTitle").html("bulbasaur") //with Jquery
```

For the description, add a id attribute to your HTML element

```
<div id="modalDescription" class="modal-body">
      Some information
</div>

document.getElementById("modalDescription").innerHTML="bulbasaur description"; // pure JS
$("#modalDescription").html("bulbasaur description") //with Jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get reference of div using id of and set content inside it.

```
//In Jquery
$('#exampleModalLongTitle').html("your text");

//In js
document.getElementById('exampleModalLongTitle').textContent = 'you text';
```